# Laravel get collection of created/updated rows

Tags: laravel, eloquent

new to laravel.

My use case:

- Update multiple rows (say: resources table).
- Create multiple users (users table).
- Retrieve ids of created users

What I currently did:

- First, Update the `resources` table `whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4])`. `(Update eloquent)`
- Second, Get array of the updated `resources` (Another eloquent: `Resource::whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4])->get()->toArray()`)
- Bulk create a users. Refers to the resources collection above. (Another eloquent: `User::create($resources)`)
- Lastly, get the ids of the created users (Not resolved yet. But I might have to use another eloquent query)

All in all, there are `4 Eloquent queries`, which I want to avoid, because this might have performance issue.

What I wanted to do is that, On first step(`Update`), I should be able to get a collection of models of the affected rows (**But I can't find any reference on how to achieve this**). And then use this collection to create the users, and get the `users ids` in one query with `User::create()` so that I will have 2 queries in total.

Answer (score 1):

To save multiple records with one query you can use

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert($data);
```

Since this won't be an eloquent method, you should pass all the columns including `created_at` and `updated_at`.

I don't know what is the method name for update.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to invent performance problems that do not exist.

Update or Insert return only count of affected rows. Commands Select, Insert, Update performed separately. This is a SQL issue, not Laravel.

For single inserts (if you want add one row) you can use insertGetId method of a model.

For example,

```
$id = User::insertGetId([
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'name' => 'john'
]);
```

But you get only ID of record. You need to run select to get full data of the row.